# Only one object usable in face select

Tags: objects, edit-mode, selection-tools

I need to select some faces on different objects to apply a material. But all of a sudden in Face Select I can only select faces of one object at a time.

The other faces are not selectable, not even by box-selecting the whole screen.
Is this some Kind of setting? How can I toggle this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. This should be the way it works  all the time? You can't select faces of separate objects simultaneously. (Only the active object is editable while in edit mode)

Answer (score 2):

Since one must be in edit mode to select a face, and one can only have one object active at a time, it is outside of the design parameters of Blender to be able to select faces on multiple objects at once.

This is not to say that you cannot apply the same material to faces on different object, you just have to select each object in turn (in object mode), switch to edit mode, and select the desired face(s), and apply the desired material.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help:

Select all the objects, join them <kbd>Strg</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>, go into edit mode, select all the faces, apply material.

Now "unjoin" each object (e.g. select one edge/face/vertex, press <kbd>L</kbd> (=select linked) or use box select) and press <kbd>P</kbd>  => selection.

I guess the effort is the same as editing each object manually + it messes up your objectnames so BE CAREFUL :)